# Select Middle Rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table where I want to select the last 10% of rows, offset by 10% (so I want to select the last 80-90% of the data).

I wrote the following query

```
SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT
   [col1], [col2]
FROM [table]
ORDER BY [col1] DESC
OFFSET 10 ROWS
```

But I receive the following error:

> Line 5: Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'.

What am I doing wrong? I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 which should be compatible with `OFFSET`

Comment: Is this the actual query that throws the error? It is valid t-sql and it works fine for me.

Comment: You can't use OFFSET with TOP. see [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this....

```
SELECT TOP (50) PERCENT *
FROM (
        SELECT TOP (20) PERCENT 
                      [col1]
                     ,[col2]
        FROM [table]
        ORDER BY [col1] DESC
     )T
ORDER BY [col1] ASC
```

Comment: Nice one! The double sort may be expensive

Comment: Thank you @Andomar,  Just been trying your suggested method against mine and it appears to me that your solution doesn't scale out very well. The larger the table is worse it gets. Here is what I have tested. [`SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72/10), the fiddle doesn't work but the query is in there and here is what the execution plans look like [`Execution Plan`](http://tinypic.com/r/2s1rukw/8). Myabe I have over looked something, but please I would like to know your thoughts about this :)

Comment: Your queries aren't using percent in the screenshot.

Comment: @MartinSmith Sorry I have tried to load the correct image but it keeps showing the old image let me try again [`Execution Plan`](http://postimg.org/image/rreybwkpv/)

Comment: Your one does benefit from having an index that avoids the need to sort the entire table. The sort operation is only against the 20%, Without the index Andomar's with `count(*) over ()` replaced with `(select count(*) from #temp)` is lower costed and faster. The windowed aggregate uses a lot more CPU time than either.

Comment: As far as I can see the extra CPU is partly down to the additional query plan operators and partly down to the overhead of evaluating the expression in the filter 1,000,000 times. The windowed aggregate plan spends about 1/8 of the time in `CEs::GeneralEval4` evaluating `(80.000000000000)<=((100.0)*CONVERT_IMPLICIT(numeric(19,0),[Expr1003],0))/CONVERT_IMPLICIT(numeric(10,0),[Expr1004],0) AND ((100.0)*CONVERT_IMPLICIT(numeric(19,0),[Expr1003],0))/CONVERT_IMPLICIT(numeric(10,0),[Expr1004],0)<(90.000000000000)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a simple good old not in:

```
SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT [col1], [col2] 
FROM [table] 
WHERE [col1] NOT IN (
    SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT [col1]
    FROM [table]
    ORDER BY [col1] DESC
)
ORDER BY [col1] DESC
```

Comment: @downvoter: care to explain? If you think something is wrong with my answer, am I suppose to guess what it is?

Answer (score 1):

For your error message, is your database set to [backwards compatibility mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933794.aspx)?

The `offset` expression only allows you to specify row numbers, not percentages.  You can select the 80-90 percentile like:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  100.0 * row_number() over (order by FirstName desc) /
                    count(*) over () as perc_pos
        from    YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   80 <= perc_pos and perc_pos < 90
```

Comment: `'row_number' is not a recognized function name.` 
I am running sql-server but i have 2005/2008 installed as well.

Comment: `row_number()` [was introduced in 2005](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.90).aspx).  Did you check your compat level?

Comment: My compatability level is for 2000 and because I have read-only access, I cannot modify it.

Comment: @Bijan SQL Server 2012 doesn't even have 2000 compatibility.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't have compatibility?

Comment: @Bijan The lowest it is possible to set compatibility level in 2012 is SQL Server 2005.

Comment: @Bijan - No it isn't because that isn't an available compatibility level there. `Select @@VERSION` will tell you the version.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for a way to present, to a web page for example, blocks of data..

Try

```
    WITH Ordered AS
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ServerName) AS 'RowNumber'
    FROM systems
) 
SELECT *
FROM Ordered
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 11 AND 20
```

With this code, I was able to offer the user the first 10, then then second block of 10 (11 - 20) and so one.

Now, a word of caution.  If you data changes frequently, this may suffer as it will give you the first 10 rows (or rows 50 to 60) at the time the query is done.

So, if new data is being added, that throws off the list, be warned.  If you looking at a list of computers, for example, and someone adds a new server named "AAA", and your looking at the middle of the list, what was item 50 in one query, may be item 49 in the second query.  (I hope I didn't confuse that even more).

Answer (score 0):

with this code, rownum get a proper rownum from a list of records available in table and pick a middle one record from them and display as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT E.*, ROWNUM RM FROM MYCODE E)
    WHERE RM=(SELECT COUNT(*)/2 FROM MYCODE);
```

Required Output of middle record from table:

[image]

Comment: This returns a singular row only, not the middle X%

Answer (score -1):

```
select top 1 *
from Employee
where empid in (
    select top 50 percent empid
    from employee
    order by empid
)
order by empid desc
```

Comment: This will not get the correct result. In fact, it will just get the first row of the `Employee` table ordered by `empid`

Answer (score -3):

```sql
declare @middle1 as int
set @middle1 = ((select COUNT(*) from [table] )+1)/2
declare @middle2 as int
set @middle2 = ((select COUNT(*) from [table] ))/2

select * from 
(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as R, * from [table] where (select COUNT(*) from [table] ) % 2 = 0) T2
where  (T2.R - @middle2 = 0) or (T2.R- @middle1 = 0)
union
select * from 
(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as R, * from [table] where (select COUNT(*) from [table] ) % 2 != 0) T2
where  T2.R - @middle1 = 0
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.